# Read PEM file from assets in flutter - Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter

main.dart:

```
main(List<String> args) async {
  String testTextFile = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/privatekey.pem');
  // rootBundle.load() returns the same error
}
```

File system:

[image]

pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/test.txt
    - assets/privatekey.pem
    - assets/publickey.pem
```

Loading either the private, public or test textfile with the above code returns `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)`.
I have tried:

- flutter clean
- recreating the project
- creating other asset folders
- trying a txt instead of a pem

Here is my flutter doctor output:

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Linux, locale en_ZA.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 3):

If your trying to do this in `main` before `runApp`, you need to make sure that the flutter engine is initialised properly. try adding `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` on the first line:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  String testTextFile = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/privatekey.pem');
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```